# How can I convert KotlinByteArray to NSData in swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KotlinByteArray as string and I want to convert it to NS Data to load the image in swift itself. anyone help me to do this please. I am using KMM Framework in Swift, it returns the KotlinByteArray for images, i want to covert it to NS Data to load image or atleast I need a way for loading the Image using KotlinByteArray

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display the images you can do it with converting the byteArray to NSData

Create an expect fun inside of the **shared** module that will return an ImageBitmap

```
@Composable
expect fun rememberImageFromBytes(bytes:ByteArray) : ImageBitmap?
```

**androidMain**

```
@Composable 
actual fun rememberImageFromBytes(bytes : ByteArray) : ImageBitmap? {
   return remember(bytes){
        if(bytes != null){
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.size).asImageBitmap()
       }else{
         null
     }
```

**iosMain**

```
@Composable 
actual fun rememberImageFromBytes(bytes : ByteArray) : ImageBitmap? {
   return remember(bytes){
        if(bytes != null){
          Bitmap.makeFromImage(
              Image.makeFromEncoded(bytes)
          ).asComposeImageBitmap()
       }else{
         null
   }
```

This will work only if you have compose multiplatform plugins enabled in your project.

And if you want to convert the byteArray to NSData you can do it using :

```
private val fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager
private val documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
         directory = NSDocumentDirectory,
         domainMask = NSUserDomainMask,
         expandTilde = true
   ).first as NSString

actual suspend fun saveImage(filename : String,bytes : ByteArray) : String {
    val path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    val data = bytes.usePinned {
            NSData.create(
                 bytes = it.addressOf(0),
                 length = bytes.size.toULong()
              )
     }
  data.writeFile(path = path,atomically = true)
```

Comment: question says nothing about compose

Comment: the second solution would work in kmm apps without compose multiplatform